# Specific value of System trace using instruments in xcode

Tags: iphone, instruments, xcode4.5

I am using the instruments check the system trace level for my application. I am got some value of system trace level  like cpu range , average memory occupying and such things.
There is an any specific value of that means default value of each of application.

Answer (score 0):

The "default value" you seek would vary greatly, depending on the amount of processes your app is running, and the level of graphics its using (OpenGLes 3D rendering, versus regular text and uiimage display.)

You can however run some diagnostic tools of common applications and see how much they tear on the system resources.